# Constant Voltage In a parallel circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, charge, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

We know that in a parallel circuit the voltage in each resistor is the same, but that doesn't make sense at all, I mean lets consider a circuit with a parallel resistance r1 and r2. V = IR is applied in the whole circuit, the constant energy of V is supplied to each electron or charge in the circuit. If r1 also gets access to V and then r2 also gets access to V then isn't the energy multiplied? Or is it that suppose there are out of a 100, 80 charges in r1 and 20 in r2 work done to push every one of the charges is same?

Comment: does your analysis work of $r_2 = \infty$? Since all circuits are in parallel with an arbitrary number of infinite resistors.

Comment: i didnt understand, It would be nice if you did not downvote it

Comment: I didn't;t down vote it, the point is: take your analysis to the limit of an extreme case where you know the answer. If it doesn't work, something is wrong.

Comment: @gsdvgsdfgsf, the word "voltage" would more properly be named "voltage drop".  There is the same voltage drop across all resistors in a parallel circuit.  Current through different resistances will vary according to I=V/R.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the voltage between two points as the potential energy that is *available* to do work per unit charge to move the charge between the two points.  Since the resistors are connected in parallel they are connected between the same two points. If a voltage $V$ is connected between those points, the same energy is available per unit charge to move the charge through each resistor.

However, it takes more work (energy) per unit charge to move the charge the greater the resistance. For a fixed voltage, that means the rate of charge between the points (I) and the power dissipated (VI) must be less if the resistance is greater.

If $r_{1}\gt r_{2}$ per Ohms law $I_{1}=V/r_{1}$ and $I_{2}=V/r_{2}$, and the total power consumption is $P_{tot}=V(I_{1}+ I_{2})=V^{2}(1/r_{1}+1/r_{2})$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Statement *the same energy is available per unit charge to move the charge through each resistor* contradicts statement *it takes more work (energy) per unit charge to move the charge the greater the resistance*.

Comment: @Farcher what I was trying to say is if the available energy per unit charge is the same the rate at which the work per unit charge is done is less for the larger resistor . I’ll reword. Thanks